# TypeError: melt() got multiple values for argument 'id_vars'

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```
  gene_name AAACGGGAGTGACTCT-1 AAAGATGCAGCGAACA-1 AAATGCCTCTGACCTC-1
0    Mrpl15                  0                  0                  0
1    Lypla1                  0                  0  0.978802530773929
2     Tcea1                  0                  0  0.978802530773929
3     Rgs20                  0                  0  0.978802530773929
```

I want to `melt` it to generate out of all of the columns except `gene_name` one column for column names and another one for values. So, according to documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html

The following should be working:

```
df = df.melt(df, id_vars=['gene_name'], value_vars=cell_ids)
```

where `cell_ids = ['AAACGGGAGTGACTCT-1','AAAGATGCAGCGAACA-1','AAATGCCTCTGACCTC-1']`

But it is giving an error:

> melt() got multiple values for argument 'id_vars'

The example is almost identical to the one in the documentation, but somehow it is not working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you're calling it as `df.melt(...)`, you don't need to pass `df` as the first argument. This will work: 
`df.melt(id_vars = 'gene_name', value_vars = cell_ids)`. Alternatively, you could call `pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'gene_name', value_vars = cell_ids)` for the same result.

Comment: Ok, was more like a typo. Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 3):

The df to melt so already definded: `df.melt()`
Thus, including it into the function, as in seaborn or matplotlib, typically required. results in an error.

You can reduce your code to:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['gene_name'])
```

by default all columns beside id_vars are taken. Therefore, you do not need to define value_vars.

reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html